# unable to remove file and directory

Tags: linux, rm

i'm trying to remove directory from my external hard drive that i mounted to the file system i'm using the `rm -r` command but i got the the strange error :

```
rm: cannot remove `Lundu nitip/Downloads/Downloads/linux-3.12.2/arch/s390/include/uapi/asm': No such file or directory
```

this is strange because when i entering the directory recursively,directory and file contain in the directory i want to remove is exist.
why does this happen? and how to remove the directory

Comment: What's the exact command line you used?

Comment: rm -r Lundu\ nitip/

where Lundu nitip is the name of the directory

Comment: try this: `find Lundu\ nitip/ -delete && rmdir Lundu\ nitip/`

Comment: Which filesystem does your external drive use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what is in the directory by listing hidden files, like;

```
$ ls -lRa directoryname
```

In Linux/Unix all files which starts with a `.` (dot) are considered hidden files

Another possibility is that you don't have permissions to remove the content -- the `-f` in `rm -rf` will cause those files you cannot remove due to permission issues to be ignored, so you can also try to issue the rm without the `f` option, like

```
rm -r directoryname
```

Additionally if the directory is a mount-point, you may have **lost access** or it may have gone into read-only mode -- To determine if that is the case you use the `mount` command and carefully examine the output.

The last is probably true, if the directory is a **NFS mounted volume** (or Windows share) where the remote machine has stopped responding

Answer (score 0):

if you have the permission to  mount a drive mount it in the nautilus(to simply see if the drive exists and is readable (in a format linux can read) and wether the file exist or not...if not found press ctr+H to show hidden files... also make sure you typed the path correctly....remember the linux terminal is case sensitive hence Directory is not the same as directory or dirEctory...